# JOptionPane Dialog Box Error

Tags: java, swing, dialog, message, joptionpane

I'm getting this error message:

```
The method showMessageDialog(Component, Object, String, int, Icon) in the type 
   JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (JFrame, String, String, int, int, ImageIcon, String)
```

When I hover over JOptionPane.showMessageDialog. I followed the java tutorial and don't know what the problem is. Any idea?

Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#button

```
String option = "Restart";
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("hangmanIcon.png");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
        "He's dead, game over. The word was " + wordList[level],
        "You Lost",
        JOptionPane.OK_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
        ic,
        option);
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Java API for JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) will tell you what method signatures are available/allowed, and that method signature isn't one. You probably want to use this one instead:

```
public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
                 Object message,
                 String title,
                 int messageType,
                 Icon icon)
                          throws HeadlessException
```

**Edit**

Perhaps what you want to use instead is not the `showMessageDialog` but rather the `showOptionDialog` which does allow for more parameters.

```
String[] options = {"Restart", "Exit"};
String option = options[0];
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("hangmanIcon.png");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
        "He's dead, game over. The word was " + wordList[level],
        "You Lost",
        JOptionPane.OK_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
        ic,
        options,
        option);
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way of doing it? The java tutorial's way of doing it was much simpler.

Comment: @Anon, what's so difficult about filling in the blanks?

Comment: @Anon: see edit. Check out the API for the `showOptionDialog` method. That's probably what you want.